# increment in view for multiply carousel purpose

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have listing of 100 properties on the same page. I use bootstrap for the view.

This is a part of the properties each loop.

```
#myCarousel.carousel.slide
    .carousel-inner
     - house.attachments.limit(9).each_with_index do |a, index| 
         %div{ :class => "#{index == 0 ? 'active item' : 'item'}" }
           = link_to(image_tag(a.file.url))


     %a.carousel-control.left{"data-slide" => "next", :href => "#myCarousel"} ‹
     %a.carousel-control.right{"data-slide" => "prev", :href => "#myCarousel"} ›
```

And this generates

```
<div class='carousel slide' id='myCarousel'>

<div class='carousel-inner'>
<div class='active item'>
<a href="/italie/umbrie/houses/tags/design-vakantiehuizen-umbrie?locale=nl"><img alt="1000-uitzicht" src="/uploads/attachment/file/1053/1000-uitzicht.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class='item'>
<a href="/italie/umbrie/houses/tags/design-vakantiehuizen-umbrie?locale=nl"><img alt="1000-stoelenbijzwembad" src="/uploads/attachment/file/1054/1000-stoelenbijzwembad.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class='item'>
<a href="/italie/umbrie/houses/tags/design-vakantiehuizen-umbrie?locale=nl"><img alt="1000-bad2" src="/uploads/attachment/file/1061/1000-bad2.jpg" /></a>
</div>
</div>
<a class='carousel-control left' data-slide='next' href='#myCarousel'>‹</a>
<a class='carousel-control right' data-slide='prev' href='#myCarousel'>›</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to add increment numbers to id mycarousel and to the control elements. Like this

```
#myCarousel1.carousel.slide
 %a.carousel-control.left{"data-slide" => "next", :href => "#myCarousel1"} ‹
 %a.carousel-control.right{"data-slide" => "prev", :href => "#myCarousel1"} ›
#myCarousel2.carousel.slide
 %a.carousel-control.left{"data-slide" => "next", :href => "#myCarousel2"} ‹
 %a.carousel-control.right{"data-slide" => "prev", :href => "#myCarousel2"} ›
ect
```

How add increment in the each_with_index loop?

thanks..remco

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of) to split in batches of 10 first. Something like (without the html):

```
group_index = 0 # unfortunately no index with in_groups_of
house.attachments.in_groups_of(10, false) do |att_group|
  # display header, start div
  # use group_index or group_index * 10 to generate id's
  att_group.each_with_index do |a, index|
    # display items
  end
  # display footer/controls
  group_counter += 1
end
```

Instead of the `group_index` incrementing each group, you can also let it increment every item if that is more convenient.